# Trying to understand an object composition pattern which features a factory and a function based mixin technique

Tags: javascript, function, object, factory, mixins

I'm trying to understand behavior of function based composition in JavaScript.

```
const Animal = (name) => {
  let properties = { name };
  return ({
    get name() { return properties.name },
    set name(newName) { properties.name = newName },
    breathe: function() {console.log(`${this.name} breathes!`); }
  })
}

const aquaticKind = (animal) => ({
  swim: () => console.log(`${animal.name} swims`)
})

const walkingKind = (animal, noOfLegs) => {
  const properties = { noOfLegs }
  return ({
    get noOfLegs() { return properties.noOfLegs },
    set noOfLegs(n) { properties.noOfLegs = n; },
    walk: () => console.log(`${animal.name} walks with ${properties.noOfLegs} legs`)
  })
}

const egglayingKind = (animal) => ({
  layEgg: () => console.log(`${animal.name} laid an egg`)
})

const Crocodile = (name) => {
  const info = Animal(name);
  return Object.assign(info,
                       walkingKind(info, 4),
                       aquaticKind(info),
                       egglayingKind(info)
                      );
}
const snooty = Crocodile('snooty');
snooty.breathe();
snooty.swim();
snooty.walk();
snooty.name = "coolie";
snooty.noOfLegs = 23 // I expected this to get update to 23
snooty.swim();
snooty.walk();
snooty.layEgg();
```

If you run the code above, you will see that `noOfLegs` never get updated, while `name` get updated. I can't seem to wrap my head around this. How do we make `noOfLegs` get updated too?

Comment: It's the `Object.assign` that's causing it - `console.log(snooty)`, you'll see that `noOfLegs` is simply a property of the object, unlike `name` for example

Comment: [MDN Documentation for object.assign shows you how to copy accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#copying_accessors)

Comment: @STN ... the title is misleading ... the presented use case does not deal with _"Function Composition"_. The example code is one of the many possibilities of how **object composition** can be achieved. Here with **a combination of function based, scope preserving (hence closures) mixins and `Object.assign`**. _Function composition_ is entirely different from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MDN Documentation for object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#copying_accessors) shows you how to copy "accessors"

Here's your code that works as expected - the `completeAssign` function is based entirely on the code in that link

```js
const completeAssign = (target, ...sources) => {
    sources.forEach(source => {
        const descriptors = Object.keys(source).reduce((descriptors, key) => {
            descriptors[key] = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source, key);
            return descriptors;
        }, {});
        Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(source).forEach(sym => {
            const descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source, sym);
            if (descriptor.enumerable) {
                descriptors[sym] = descriptor;
            }
        });
        Object.defineProperties(target, descriptors);
    });
    return target;
};

const Animal = (name) => {
    const properties = { name };
    return ({
        get name() { return properties.name },
        set name(newName) { properties.name = newName },
        breathe () { console.log(`${this.name} breathes!`); }
    })
}

const aquaticKind = (animal) => ({ 
    swim: () => console.log(`${animal.name} swims`) 
});

const walkingKind = (animal, noOfLegs) => {
    const properties = { noOfLegs };
    return ({
        get noOfLegs() { return properties.noOfLegs },
        set noOfLegs(n) { properties.noOfLegs = n; },
        walk: () => console.log(`${animal.name} walks with ${properties.noOfLegs} legs`)
    })
}

const egglayingKind = (animal) => ({
    layEgg: () => console.log(`${animal.name} laid an egg`)
})

const Crocodile = (name) => {
    const info = Animal(name);
    return completeAssign(info,
        walkingKind(info, 4),
        aquaticKind(info),
        egglayingKind(info)
    );
}
const snooty = Crocodile('snooty');
snooty.breathe();
snooty.swim();
snooty.walk();
snooty.name = "coolie";
snooty.noOfLegs = 23;
snooty.swim();
snooty.walk();
snooty.layEgg();
```